# Automate Deployment from windows server to Linux/Raspbian

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, continuous-deployment, automated-deploy

How can I automate the build and deployment process from Windows server as a controlling machine to multiple Linux (Raspbian OS) as node machine. Is there any tool which takes care of cross platform deployment, if yes then suggest ?

Comment: Ansible can be a good option. It runs within Python and so is cross platform

Comment: @RamanSailopal I've gone through ansible but it works with WSL(Linux terminal in Windows) but I'm specifically looking for GUI. So in this case Ansible Tower can help me ? I'm very new to automate deployment.